# Framework selection how to?

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks

Could somebody tell what do I have to add as framework if I want to have the latest/newest version?

[image: framework selection]

Comment: which xcode version are u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, they are all the same.
You can check it by doing:
`ls -al /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz*` and you'll get the following:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     16 Sep 20 13:58 libz.1.1.3.dylib -> libz.1.2.5.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  79104 Sep 20 13:58 libz.1.2.5.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     16 Sep 20 13:58 libz.1.dylib -> libz.1.2.5.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     16 Sep 20 13:58 libz.dylib -> libz.1.2.5.dylib
```

as a more general rule, the one without a version number is a symbolic link to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

in iOS 6 SDK, goto Target > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries > click + > and type the required framework name > double click the framework.